# What happens when SVN isn't used?

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

I am wondering what happens in SVN when a file is updated directly instead of using SVN?  The main reason I am asking is that there was a problem updating the SVN on my machine (windows) when the server (linux) had 2 names that were the same, but different case.  I resolved this on the server, but didn't do it through SVN since it won't update correct, but I still get the issue.  Do I need to run some kind of command to update it?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I deleted the comflicting file in the working direcotry and wanted to know if doing things directory in the working directory get tracked at all or what needs to be done to resync.

Comment: You updated the file directly in the repository, or in your working directory? It's unclear what you're asking, because the entire point of svn is that you edit the files with other editors and then commit your changes.

Comment: I added to the question.  The working directory is where I deleted a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When SVN gets blocked because the repository is more "up to date" than the local checkout, one brain dead foolproof solution is:

1. Move (or remove) the files that are causing the conflict at the command line (don't use SVN tools to do this, and don't use the GUI if you have tortoise installed).
2. svn update the repository, which will restore the current copy of the files from the subversion server.
3. Decide what to do with your cached copies of the old files.  Either manually merge them back into the repository, discard them, or remake the changes in the new svn managed files (depending on your needs).

Note that if you move the files into a directory using tortoise, make sure that you move it into a directory that's not associated with ANY SVN project.  It's not fun trying to undo the helpful changes tortoise does in thinking your wanting a SVN move to accompany the file system move.

Comment: Even though the answer didn't directly answer my issue, it helped me get the solution.  I had to use svn del command to delete the image in the repository to match the working directory.

Comment: @fanfavorite, Well, it's my brain dead solution because it doesn't actually attempt to understand the situation.  That said, sometimes understanding the situation is not necessary, just a quick correction is called for to get working again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to run any special commands. If you updated the sources, the next time you will run `svn update` subversion will seamlessly merge the changes and you will get an uptodate working copy.

If you changed some files, they will appear modified or conflicted depending on the changes made by you and other users.

Comment: When I run svn update /path on the server in the command line, I get skipped '/path'.  Is there something I am missing?